# pointgrey camera works only once

Tags: ros, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch my camera using:

```
roslaunch pointgrey_camera_driver camera.launch
```

it starts working and publishing all topics, very normal!

Then I launch my node that subscribe to `/camera/image_raw` and it works fine.
But when I shut down my node and launch it again, it doesn't work! even though the topic is still published.

Also

```
rostopic echo /camera/image_raw
```

doesn't give anything after that.

I noticed I get that error:

```
[ERROR] [1491313248.152009223]: PointGreyCamera::grabImage Failed to retrieve buffer | FlyCapture2::ErrorType 41 There is an image consistency issue with this image.
```

What's the issue?

I'm using:

Ubuntu 16.04

ROS kinetic

Camera Blackfly 0.9 MP Color GigE PoE (Sony ICX692)

Driver camera:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258537/pointgrey-camera-works-only-once/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The image packets are getting dropped, might be due to bandwidth congestion. Try increasing the packet delay or decreasing the packet size.
Have a look at these two:

[Increase Packet Delay](https://www.ptgrey.com/tan/10351)

[Increase PC Buffer capacity](http://www.ptgrey.com/KB/10016)

---

Originally posted by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) with karma: 63 on 2017-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0